# Databales using initComplete not work when the data is not not from ajax but local

Tags: javascript, ajax, local-storage

I am using the plugin databales to display my data. And now I want to add a select box, its value is from the data. When the data is loaded using ajax, it work well. The code is like this:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "/api/mydata/",
    dataSrc: "results",
  },
  columns: [
  ...
  ],
  initComplete: function () {
    var cellTypes = table.column(2).data().unique().toArray();
    var selectOptions = cellTypes.map(function (cellType) {
      return '<option value="' + cellType + '">' + cellType + "</option>";
    });
    $("#cellTypeFilter").append(selectOptions.join(""));
    $("#cellTypeFilter").on("change", function () {
      var selectedCellType = $(this).val();
      table.column(2).search(selectedCellType).draw();
    });
   })
```

The variable cellTypes is the unique value of third column in data, and I have defind select option which id is "cellTypeFilter" before. All things work well  at this time.

Howerver, when I change the source of data, and in fact, I want to get the data from localStorge before request from remote server, so I change the code:

```
var cachedData = localStorage.getItem("cachedDataTableData");
   
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
   data: CacheData
   ...
```

Other code is the same with above. But this time the select options is empty, and when i print the 'cellTypes' inside the initComplete function, i get undefined.

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
   data: CacheData
   ...
initComplete: function () {
   var cellTypes = table.column(2).data().unique().toArray();
   console.log(cellTypes)
   ...
```

So why can't I get the vaule when the data is from localStorge, and how can i modify my code to work in both situtation?

Comment: You might want to use `drawCallback` instead of `initComplete`